# MySQL multiple joins & remove duplicates

Tags: mysql, select, join

Quick update -- SQLFiddle link: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d038f/2

I think it's a relatively straight forward one...

I have 7 tables altogether, 3 'main' tables, another 3 that manages the 'many-to-many' relationships and another one which is the master table, more precisely:

```
mysql> show tables;
+--------------------+
| Tables_in_test     |
+--------------------+
| Equipment          |
| Room               |
| Trainer            |
| Training           |
| training_equipment |
| training_room      |
| training_trainer   |
+--------------------+
7 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Now, the schemas and contents:

```
    mysql> SELECT * FROM Equipment; 
           SELECT * FROM Room; 
           SELECT * FROM Trainer; 
           SELECT * FROM training_equipment; 
           SELECT * FROM training_room; 
           SELECT * FROM training_trainer; 
           SELECT * FROM Training;   



+----+-------------+
| id | equipment   |
+----+-------------+
|  1 | Equipment_1 |
|  2 | Equipment_2 |
|  3 | Equipment_3 |
|  4 | Equipment_4 |
+----+-------------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)

+----+--------+
| id | room   |
+----+--------+
|  1 | Room_1 |
|  2 | Room_2 |
+----+--------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

+----+-------+
| id | name  |
+----+-------+
|  1 | John  |
|  2 | Joe   |
|  3 | Jason |
+----+-------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)


+-------------+--------------+
| training_id | equipment_id |
+-------------+--------------+
|           1 |            3 |
|           1 |            4 |
|           2 |            1 |
+-------------+--------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

+-------------+---------+
| training_id | room_id |
+-------------+---------+
|           1 |       1 |
+-------------+---------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)

+-------------+------------+
| training_id | trainer_id |
+-------------+------------+
|           1 |          2 |
|           1 |          3 |
+-------------+------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

+----+------------+------------+---------+------+-----------+---+
| id | from       | to         | trainer | room | equipment | a |
+----+------------+------------+---------+------+-----------+---+
|  1 | 1349578297 | 1350096689 |       1 |    1 |         1 | 0 |
+----+------------+------------+---------+------+-----------+---+
1 row in set (0.02 sec)
```

I came up with the following query and you can see that the result is not correct:

```
mysql> SELECT t.from, r.room, tra.name, e.equipment
    -> FROM Training t
    -> LEFT JOIN training_room tr ON ( t.room = tr.training_id )
    -> LEFT JOIN Room r ON ( tr.room_id = r.id )
    -> LEFT JOIN training_trainer tt ON ( t.trainer = tt.training_id )
    -> LEFT JOIN Trainer tra ON ( tt.trainer_id = tra.id )
    -> LEFT JOIN training_equipment te ON ( t.equipment = te.training_id)
    -> LEFT JOIN Equipment e ON ( te.equipment_id = e.id )
    -> WHERE t.id =1;
+------------+--------+------+-------------+
| from       | room   | name | equipment   |
+------------+--------+------+-------------+
| 1349578297 | Room_1 | Joe  | Equipment_3 |
| 1349578297 | Room_1 | Joe  | Equipment_4 |
| 1349578297 | Room_1 | Jason| Equipment_3 |
| 1349578297 | Room_1 | Jason| Equipment_4 |
+------------+--------+------+-------------+
4 rows in set (0.02 sec)
```

I don't want to see duplicate results, all I'd like to see would be:

```
+------------+--------+------+-------------+
| from       | room   | name | equipment   |
+------------+--------+------+-------------+
| 1349578297 | Room_1 | Joe  | Equipment_3 |
| 1349578297 | Room_1 | Jason| Equipment_4 |
+------------+--------+------+-------------+
```

`DISTINCT` doesn't solve the problem nor does `GROUP BY tra.name, e.equipment`

Thank you.

Comment: can you make sqlfiddle ?

Comment: Did you try `DISTINCT equipment` and `GROUP BY name`?

Comment: also better to show dump of tables, intead of select, or at least 
`SHOW CREATE TABLE`

Comment: eicto: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d038f/2

Comment: sorry it took me some time - first time I'm using sqlfiddle, thanks for the advise.

Comment: What table links Joe with Equipment_3 and Jason with Equipment_4?

Comment: Your requirement is not sufficient.  You have a link between (Joe) and (Equip3 -and- Equip4), but also (Jason) -and- (Equip3 -and- Equip4), but your result has only (Joe, Equip3) -and- (Jason, Equip4).  It's really not clear which Equip* is intended to be shown with which Trainer.  Room1 maps to both Joe and Jason, but you seem that room for both, not just for one.  You seem to want DISTINCT in some senses, but not in others.  So define your concept of (duplicate) clearly first.  Without that clear requirement, a correct answer is not possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sorry, but with your current database structure, i think there's no query to match your requirement.
But you can check the group_concat() function, it can group the equipment and trainer name into a string. and then you can extract the value by use server code like php.

```
 SELECT t.from, r.room, group_concat(distinct tra.name), group_concat( distinct e.equipment)
 FROM Training t
 LEFT JOIN training_room tr ON ( t.room = tr.training_id )
 LEFT JOIN Room r ON ( tr.room_id = r.id )
 LEFT JOIN training_trainer tt ON ( t.trainer = tt.training_id )
 LEFT JOIN Trainer tra ON ( tt.trainer_id = tra.id )
 LEFT JOIN training_equipment te ON ( t.equipment = te.training_id)
 LEFT JOIN Equipment e ON ( te.equipment_id = e.id )
 WHERE t.id =1
```

If you can change the structure of table "training_equipment", add another column "trainer_id" then you can use the query below:

```
SELECT t.from, r.room, tra.name, e.equipment
FROM Training t
LEFT JOIN training_room tr ON ( t.room = tr.training_id )
LEFT JOIN Room r ON ( tr.room_id = r.id )     
LEFT JOIN training_equipment te ON ( t.equipment = te.training_id)
LEFT JOIN Equipment e ON ( te.equipment_id = e.id )
LEFT JOIN Trainer tra ON ( te.trainer_id = tra.id )
WHERE t.id =1
```